# Can we burninate shared?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burnination-request

[shared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shared) is useless. Just completely and utterly useless.

It doesn't refer to anything currently, is used all over the place (shared folders/shared libraries/shared memory), and has no definition for obvious reasons. Each of those reasons have their own specific tag already:

- [sharing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sharing) for data (even though this is still pretty bad)
- [shared-library](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shared-library) for shared libraries
- [memory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/memory) for shared memory (as it really doesn't need its own tag)

It, all in all, just does not seem to be a good tag.

Can we get rid of it, pretty please?

---

**Note:** While this is a burnination request, this is *not* a blacklist request. It is very likely that a sharing daemon called `shared` may exist one day. If this happens, we shouldn't have that tag pre-blacklisted. But, until that day, this tag is useless. Useless!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Done.

Comment: What? A 5-character answer?

Comment: @Dev [Magic.](http://media.giphy.com/media/VHngktboAlxHW/giphy-downsized-large.gif)

Comment: Yes.᠎​᠎​᠎​᠎​᠎​᠎